# Number of decimal digits in a double

Tags: java, double

How do I determine number of integer digits and the number of digits after decimal in a number like `234.12413` in Java.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993124/problem-on-getting-digits-in-a-double-variable/5993212#5993212

Comment: For what possible feature of an application, would the program need to know that?  Surely it is more a matter of displaying a `Double` or `Float` to show only a certain limit of precision.  E.G. '12.158384' -> '12.16', '3.33333..' -> '3.33'.

Comment: There are no decimal digits in a double. There are binary digits.

Comment: Another way of looking at it:  A double, at the hardware level on Intel platforms, is a 52-bit integer.  And there is an 11-bit number that tells you where to put the decimal point.  And one more bit for sign.

Comment: Compared to casting String, I would like to recommend this. 
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(<double_value>);
int decimalCount = Math.max(0, value .scale());

Comment: You can convert to BigDecimal and do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296110/determine-number-of-decimal-place-using-bigdecimal

Comment: `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleNumber)).scale()`. Ref: baeldung.com/java-separate-double-into-integer-decimal-parts

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A double is not always an exact representation.  You can only say how many decimal places you would have if you converted it to a String.

```
double d= 234.12413;
String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(d));
int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
int decimalPlaces = text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

This will only work for numbers which are not turned into exponent notation.  You might consider 1.0 to have one or no decimal places.

Comment: BigDecimal is more useful when exponent comes.anyway goodexample so +1

Comment: This method will fail eventually, because the conversion `toString()` uses the decimal separator of the OS, not all OSs use dot `.` as decimal separator and you are using a literal dot, hence it will work only in some environments and under some circumstances. A better approach would be to use: `new DecimalFormat("#.#########").format(Math.abs(value)).replace(",",".")` to ensure your `text` variable always receive a literal dot.

Comment: Also it does not work for high numbers ending with zeros because 10000000 is represented as 1.0E7 etc. Therefore result[0] = 1 and result[1] = 3. `DecimalFormat` would help. The same problem have other solutions with `toString()` or `"" + doubleValue`

Comment: This is a decent answer, however it is not reliable because it does not work for any double. I was able to solve this answer using mathematics by looping through the powers of ten, and checking to see if `dbl * pow(10, i) % 1 == 0` was true. If that statement was true, then the number of decimal places is `i`. Adding an `if` at the beginning of the method to check if the double has no decimal: `if(dbl == (int)dbl) {return 0;}` completes the method.

Comment: @IanS. "it does not work for any double" Can you give an example as I did?

Comment: A counterexample to your solution would be, as Fenix said, 10,000,000. `Double.toString(10000000)` returns `1.0E7`. However, if you ran this number through my method, then `10000000.0D * Math.pow(10, 0) % 1 == 0` would be true, and the function would return 0. Unfortunately there are not enough characters per comment to fit the full implementation of the method. (I revised the method so there is no if-statement at the top anymore).

Comment: @IanS. I have this note already `This will only work for numbers which are not turned into exponent notation` Are there other examples?

Comment: Not that I can find at the moment, but in my opinion, a mathematical solution is more reliable than an OS-dependent solution. I find that the mathematical solution was a good fit for what I was using it for at the time (double to `byte[]` conversion). The `Double.toString()` method is more practical for everyday use, however there are a few pitfall values that one must look out for. (P.S. you could add this to your method: `if(text.matches("[+-]?\\d+\\.\\d+E-\\d+")) return Integer.parseInt(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('-')));`

Comment: @IanS. Java shouldn't be OS independent (it can be locale dependant)

Comment: @JoeAlmore You got that reversed. `toString()` will always use '.' ('\u002E') (explicitly mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-)). It is `DecimalFormat` that will use a Locale-dependent decimal separator.

Comment: @IanS Unfortunately, there are still edge cases that wouldn't work: `0.29d * 100d = 28.999999999999996`. So `0.29d * 100d % 1` should ideally be `0` but it's actually `0.9999999999999964` :/

Comment: @dcastro c.f. try `1 % 0.1` ;)

Comment: This would be a better approach. `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleNumber)).scale()`. Ref: baeldung.com/java-separate-double-into-integer-decimal-parts

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera Can you say what makes this better? e.g. clarity, speed, accuracy, edge cases?

Comment: your solution won't work if the number is without decimal digits, will return 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 22):

```
Double d = 234.12413;
String[] splitter = d.toString().split("\\.");
splitter[0].length();   // Before Decimal Count
splitter[1].length();   // After  Decimal Count
```

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey: it is `Double` here not `double`, capital **D** ouble

Comment: decimalno=dstring.length()-(dstring.indexOf(".")+1);

Comment: If `\\.` regex does not work, try `[.]`. It did work for me

Answer (score 10):

```
    String s = "" + 234.12413;
    String[] result = s.split("\\.");
    System.out.println(result[0].length() + " " + result[1].length());
```

Answer (score 3):

1) convert to string

2) substring from '.' to end

3) get the length of this substring