# How to validate a decimal number to have precision exactly one?

Tags: c#

I need to validate user input into a textbox to be a decimal number of precision exactly one? For example below are some of the cases..

- if user inputs 1 then it's invalid
- if user inputs 0 then its invalid
- if user inputs 1.0 then its valid
- if user inputs 1.1 then its valid
- if user inputs 1.11 then its invalid
- if user inputs 100.1 then its valid

How can I achieve this using C#(.net 3.5)?

Its a WPF textbox.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, Silverlight? Client-side validation (i.e. JavaScript) or Server-side or both?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double and check splitted.Length > 1 && splitted[1].Length = 1

Comment: wpf winfroms or asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-regex way of achieving this:

```
string input;
decimal deci;
if (input.Length >=3 && input[input.Length - 2].Equals('.') && Decimal.TryParse(input , out deci))
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Fail
}
```

Comment: I would recommend the regex method of doing this. I originally answered this in my naive early days :)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, to me, seems to be to use regular expressions. By interpreting the user input as a string, you can compare it with something like `'[0-9]+\.[0-9]'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes regular expression is the best way to check your condition:

For exactly NNNN.N (1234.5) use:

```
/^\d{4}\.\d$/
```

For optional .N (1234 1234. 1234.5) go with:

```
/^\d{4}(\.\d?)?$/
```

For numbers up to size of NNNN.N (1 .5 12.5 123. 1234 1234.5) go with:

```
/^(?=.*\d)\d{0,4}(\.\d?)?$/
```

And if you want to allow +/- at the beginning, then replace ^ with ^[-+]?.