# regular expression for latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, regex, range, decimal

I want the regular expression for checking valid `lat/long for india only`.The longitude range is 70-98 with one decimal places and latitude range is 8-36 with one decimal place

I have implemented this in android. This code I've written for the range of -90 to 90 and -180 to 180 for lat and along respectively and it is working but now my range for lat and long is changed.

For the decimal point it should allow 8.0 to 36.0.

```
public class Manual_LatLong extends Activity

{

private EditText LAT1;

private EditText LONGITUDE1;

private static final String TAG_LAT = "LAT";

private static final String TAG_LONG = "LONGITUDE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual__lat_long);

    LAT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    LONGITUDE1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    findViewById(R.id.show).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             String LAT = LAT1.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidLAT(LAT)) {
                LAT1.setError("Invalid Latitude");
                LAT1.requestFocus(LAT.length());

            }
            else{

                 String LONGITUDE = LONGITUDE1.getText().toString();
                 if (!isValidLONG(LONGITUDE)) {
                    LONGITUDE1.setError("Invalid LONGITUDE");
                    LONGITUDE1.requestFocus(LONGITUDE.length());
                }
                 else{
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationActivity.class);
                    // Sending lat/long to next activity
                    in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, LAT);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_LONG, LONGITUDE);
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                 }

             }


        }
    });
}

private boolean isValidLAT(String LAT) {
    String LAT_PATTERN = "(-?[0-8]?[0-9](\\.\\d*)?)|-?90(\\.[0]*)?";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(LAT_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(LAT);
    return matcher.matches();
}


private boolean isValidLONG(String LONGITUDE) {
    String LONG_PATTERN = "(-?([1]?[0-7][1-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])?(\\.\\d*)?)|-?180(\\.[0]*)?";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(LONG_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(LONGITUDE);
    return matcher.matches();

}
```

}

Comment: for lattitude i have tried this:PATTERN = "(?[7-9]?[0-8](\\.\\d*)?)"but it is showing me syntax error.

Comment: How are you using this variable, in which language, what's the error message? Please update your question.

Comment: If this is shell script, you cannot have whitespace around the equals sign, and many of the standard regex tools (`grep` etc) don't support Perl extensions like `\d`.

Comment: (Might as well fix the spelling of "latitude" in the question title then.)

Comment: By "with one decimal place" do you mean the last range ends at 36.0? So 35.9 is fine but 36.1 is not? Or do you mean up through 36.9?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be one of the worst things to use Regex for. Can't you just convert it to a double?

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(R.id.editText1.getText().toString());
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(R.id.editText2.getText().toString();
```

And compare using if (latitude < 36 && latitude... etc)?

EDIT:

If it has to be one decimal place at most:

```
String latitude_s = R.id.editText1.getText().toString();
String longitude_s = R.id.editText2.getText().toString();
```

And check each string if it only has one decimal point first IF it has a decimal point. (Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double) how to check for decimal places)

After that you can proceed comparing the doubles.

Comment: thank u for your reply but with this how can i get one decimal point latitude and longitude.

Comment: Are you saying your latitude and longitude should only be one decimal place? Meaning 8.1 is valid latitude but 8.12 isn't?

Comment: Why are more accurate co-ordinates invalid?