# Print a Double as a String with unknown decimal length

Tags: java

I need to print a Double as a String but I don't know how many decimal places there will be and I have to be prepared for as many as possible.  Right, now I'm using this ugly solution:

```
Double dubs = 0.000157;

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(
    "##.########################################################################################");
System.out.println(formatter.format(dubs));
```

Comment: Doubles can't have that many decimals in the first place.

Comment: Why do you even need to convert it to a string? Why not just print it?

Comment: because it prints in scientific notation and that doesn't meet my requirements

Comment: in double number, you need to precise the number of digit after the dot (.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with no conversion:

```
public class codesnippets {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Double dubs = 0.000157;
     System.out.printf("%f", dubs);
 }

}
```

You can also use

```
Double dubs = 0.000157;
String dubs_format = String.format("%f", dubs);
System.out.println(dubs);
```

EDIT: Apparently there is a precision loss when using "%f" as a format string. If this is the case for you, use "%.10f"

Comment: since it is a double wouldn't it be %lf?

Comment: @Tyler this is Java, not C

Comment: Ok but to be clear I need an actual String object in order to place it in an XML document

Comment: Yes but I assumed Java would follow the same formats for printf, that's why I asked. Cheers

Comment: This seems to work, extrapolated from your idea:        String dubString= String.format("%f", dubs);
 System.out.println(dubString);

Comment: Nice. I’ll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Steampunkery  Can you advise, If Double dubs = 0.000157001;

Comment: @SamDev it should be the same. What’s your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try here man. I think this is what you're saying. The answer given at the bottom.

[Number of decimal digits in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double)

Here is what I meant.

```
double d= 234.12413;
String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(d));
int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
int decimalPlaces = text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

Then you just concatenate them

```
String xmlString = integerPlaces.toString() + "." + decimalPlaces.toString();
```

Comment: Please don’t post link only answers.

Comment: I can't comment yet. Should I repeat someone else's answer ?

Comment: Flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't realize that was an option yet. I see that I can now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work based on Steampunkery's idea.  The catch was that I needed an actual String which I realize I wasn't clear on.

```
String dubString= String.format("%f", dubs); 
System.out.println(dubString);
```