# How to find the difference in decimal points in Java

Tags: java

Let us say we have the following numbers:

```
23.499999959800466
23.49999995949621
23.49999995980162
23.499999956586194
23.499999954013447
23.499999959041133
```

By looking at them, one can notice the difference in the `9th` decimal point. My question is how to identify such a difference in Java?

Comment: `if (number1 != number2) ...` ?

Comment: number1 - number2 => difference

Comment: Why do you mean about identifying such difference? There are some questions here about how to get the number of digits after the decimal if that's the question. [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double)

Comment: @Stultuske if you're not using a Decimal class that would lead to float rounding errors.

Comment: @Tschallacka to find the difference, it's a simple subtraction. Somehow I assume it's already using a decimal type.

Answer (score 1):

If you know two numbers have the same integer part, use base 10 log:

```
double n1 = 23.499999959800466d;
double n2 = 23.49999995949621d;

// index of the last identical decimal place between n1 and n2
int decimalDiff = (int) Math.abs(Math.log10(n1 - n2));

System.out.println(decimalDiff);
```

Output: `9`

If you have many numbers **and** you know they all have the same integer part, then calculate the decimal difference between the smallest and largest of the list:

```
List<Double> numbers = Arrays.asList(
                23.499999959800466, 
                23.49999995949621, 
                23.49999995980162,
                23.499999956586194, 
                23.499999954013447, 
                23.499999959041133);

        double smallest = Collections.min(numbers);
        double largest = Collections.max(numbers);

        System.out.println((int) -Math.log10(largest - smallest));
```

Output: `8`. The numbers all have 8 decimal places in common.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **java.math.BigDecimal** class for your solution.

The **BigDecimal** class provides operations on double numbers for arithmetic, scale handling, rounding, **comparison**, format conversion and hashing. It **can handle very large and very small floating point numbers** with great precision but compensating with the time complexity a bit.
A **BigDecimal** consists of a random precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale. If greater than or equal to zero, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.**strong text**.

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(num);
```

**Java BigDecimal Methods**

**BigDecimal add(BigDecimal bigDecimal2)**

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("233233233233");
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(bigInt);
BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal(55662.3);
System.out.println(bigDecimal.add(bigDecimal2));
```

**BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal bigDecimal2):**

```
bigDecimal.subtract(bigDecimal2)
```

You can use subtract method of BigDecimal class for you solution and easily compute difference between two BigDecimal number.

**BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode):**

You can also set scale for numbers using setScale function.

**UP:** to round away from zero

**CEILING:** to round towards positive infinity

**DOWN:** to round towards zero

**FLOOR:** to round towards negative infinity

**HALF_DOWN:** to round towards “nearest neighbor” unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down

**HALF_EVEN:** to round towards the “nearest neighbor” unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor

**HALF_UP:** to round towards “nearest neighbor” unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up

**UNNECESSARY:** to assert that the requested operation has an exact result, hence no rounding is necessary

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("23323323.3533");
bigDecimal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.CEILING)
bigDecimal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN)
bigDecimal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.FLOOR)
```

**Output:**

23323323.3533

**CEILING**: 23323323.36

**DOWN**: 23323323.35

**FLOOR**: 23323323.35

Hope this will help.